# Firebase Auth not working for iOS App, while firestore and android version working fine

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

firebase authentication is not working on my flutter iOS app. While I have no problem on the android app, I get `ERROR INTERNAL_ERROR` when trying to sign in with email or create user with email. Firebase firestore works fine.

I'm using these dependencies:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1
cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
firebase_performance: ^0.3.0+5
```

I tried everything I could imagine: deleting and rebuilding the `ios` folder, updating the firebase dependencies, deleting the iOS app in the firebase console and downloading another `googleService-Info.plist`. Nothing helped.

I also tried creating a new firebase project and tested authentication on this one. Oddly this project is working, which leads me to the conclusion, that the problem is on the firebase project side.

Any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Which dependency are you using?

Comment: @Rob updated the question about that

Comment: Have you followed everything mentioned in here -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?

Comment: yes I have, also if I wouldn't, it would make no sense, that firestore works but not authentication, except maybe activation the sign in methods, but email authentication is activated

Comment: Can you show me what have you done? May be after seeing it all, I may find the bug.

Comment: Do you mean show you the whole project? Sadly I can't do that but I can show you code snippets. Although I highly doubt it's a bug in my code, because as said, the code works for the android version

Comment: Run on iOS simulator and tell me what is the value for `_auth` using this: `final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;`?

Comment: Its just a regular instance of the FirebaseAuth instance. I appreciate your help but I don't see how this could be the problem, because the exact same code works for android